# Nuget Package Resx Localization

Tags: c#, localization, uwp, nuget-package, resx

I have a nuget package that contains Resx files, for instance MyResources.resx and MyResources.fr.resx.

I have a UWP app which references this nuget package. In my Nuspec file I configured the resx dlls for each language to be copied to the project that references the nuget package. At the end when I compile the project that references this pacakge I can find one folder called "fr" which contains a dll for the resources.

Now, this nuget package is a library that contains a class that uses the resources, for instance I have a property that returns MyResources.MyLabel;

If I add the project from which I create the nuget package directly onto my app solution and then reference the project directly, when I run my app and I change my region and language I can see the label being translated.

The error comes when I reference the nuget package instead of the project directly then whenever I get the label I always get it in English. It does not recognize the culture or maybe the file containing the labels is not found.

Any suggestions? I havent been able to find the fix for this or any discussion related to this scenario. I also set my resx files to be public so I can actually go into my app and call the resource directly but it still only in english no matter what.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue? Besides, .resx file is not used in UWP. For UWP apps, we should use **.resw** file. Resx dll won't be able to work in UWP.

Comment: Hi Scavenger, it seems like a UWP bug right now. Although UWP uses .resw files if you set this solution without nuget packages referencing the projects directly, the resw files are generated automatically and then it works. When you put it through nuget package though something is missing. A bug has been reported here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2696